# Is there any difference in perofrmance of unordered_set (C++) in case of strings vs in case of integer?

Tags: c++, string, integer, unordered-map, unordered-set

I was wondering that unordered_set uses hashing, so that should be faster in the case of integers than in the case of strings. The same would be the case for unordered_map. I found no definite answer on the web. It will be great if someone can clarify this.

Comment: Do you want to benchmark `std::hash<std::string>` versus `std::hash<int>`?

Comment: The exact performance would be very dependent on the specific hash implementations and data inputs, you would need to profile. That said, I would certainly expect hashing integers to be no slower than hashing strings, but I can imagine cases where they are about equivalent. If your strings are all very short, and therefore stored directly inside a `std::string` object with the short string optimisation, no indirection, then hashing a few bytes stored directly in the key isn't really going to care what the type system says about those bytes.

Comment: Well, the calculation of the hash itself tends to be proportional to the size of the data being hashed, but it's hard to see how it helps that hashing ints is faster than hashing strings if what you have are strings.

Comment: I want to hash 64 character string vs hashing an integer (4 bytes). In my case, I think there is a considerable difference in size. For short string, no doubt there won't be any noticeable difference

Comment: Maybe a little OT: I remember this talk of this guy from Ubisoft, he says that they don't ship games with maps that have a string as key, [here](https://youtu.be/qYN6eduU06s), he also says that they use custom containers, so maybe it is not applicable with STL containers. But maybe what he is saying is correlated with what you are asking. I would be curious to know where the truth is! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any difference in perofrmance of unordered_set (C++) in case of strings vs in case of integer?

There can be. The language specification doesn't have guarantees one way or the other.

You can verify whether this is the case for your program on your target system by measuring the performance.

---

If you're considering whether to use string itself as the key, or a separately hashed string (i.e. integer), then technically separate hashing is more expensive since the integer would be hashed again. That said, hashing an integer is trivial (I think it may be the identity function), so this might have no noticeable effect.

Separate hashing + storing integer does have potential advantage: You can pre-hash the string keys once, and reuse the hashed integer key, while a map with string keys requires the key to be re-hashed on every lookup. Whether this is useful in your case depends on what you're going to do with the map.

Answer (score 1):

The abstract answer would be "depends on implementation and other details" like sizes of keys and containers. Standard doesn't specify anything around strings vs ints, so you should not expect that there is globally valid answer.

On popular platforms like gcc / clang on on x86 / x86_64 your guess seems about right. I have experience of getting essential performance wins after replacing string keys in maps with ints or pointers.

Still, there're might be specific circumstances when strings will beat ints even on mentioned platforms.

Comment: note that strings vs ints in a `map` can be slower because strings are more expensive than ints in general, while OP is specifically asking for the hash

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number this is what I'm saying: on popular platform hashing of strings often is slower than hashing of ints.

Comment: you are saying "I have experience of getting essential performance wins after replacing string keys in maps with ints or pointers." this might be due to strings reallocating or creating strings is more expensive than creating an int.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number well, correct. Still it makes sense to expect win on hashing side too because hash of integer is it's value while for string it's defined in a bit more complicated way.

Comment: matter of opinion, mine is: It does not make sense to expect anything about performance unless you measure it ;). Nevermind, probably you are right

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number exacto :) This is just worthy pattern to have on mind.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing functions aren't specified by the C++ Standard.

That said, GCC, Clang and Visual C++ all use an identify hash for integers - meaning the `std::hash<>` specialised for integer types returns its input.  Visual C++ uses power-of-2 bucket counts, while GCC uses prime numbers.  Consequently, certain inputs are extremely collision-prone on Visual C++, e.g. pointers to objects with N-byte alignment - where N is largish - that have been converted to numbers will all collide at buckets 0, N, 2N, 3N etc. with all the buckets in between storing no data.  On the other hand, if the integers are random enough that they happen to distribute well across the buckets without excessive collisions (which is much more likely with GCC's prime bucket count), then an identity hash saves CPU time in trying to further process them.

GCC uses MURMUR32 hashing for strings, while Visual C++ does some simple xoring and shifting on 10 characters roughly evenly sampled along the string (so, GCC is slower but massively better hash quality, particularly for things like same-length directory/filename paths with common prefixes and just an incrementing code at the end, where Visual C++ may only incorporate a single different character into the hash).  Compared to a string storing its text inside itself (a technique known as Short String Optimisation or SSO) or an integer, any string storing longer text in dynamically allocated memory ("heap"), will depend on at least one extra least one extra cache line to reach the text (and on modern x86 architectures, an extra cache fault may be needed for each 64-byte chunk of the string accessed during hashing).

It is possible to create an object to store a string and a hash - calculated once - but that's not exactly what the question asks about, and after finding a match on hash value you still need to compare the entire string content to be certain of a match.

In conclusion, if you use the default identify hashing with collision-prone keys on Visual C++, it *may* be slower than using strings (if the strings hash with fewer collisions, which is far from certain).  But, in most cases using integer keys will be faster.

If you really care, always benchmark on your own system and dataset.